# Prevent Expression Blend to "run" the application when XAML tabs are open

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

Expression Blend behaves in a very interesting way with a lot of applications I develop:

Depending on how the hookup is done regarding views and viewmodels, the application just "starts working" from inside the designer tabs, displaying, for example, connected usb devices the application manages, and even displaying live preview of USB cameras plugged in.

But currently I have some threads that are started when application runs, and I noticed the designer and the xaml editor become "frozen" for a short time, periodically, apparently because of some busy routines inside a loop found in one of my classes.

To make matters worse, I cannot even run the application in Visual Studio if it is open in Blend at the same time (a common setup for me), because the relevant USB devices are already taken over by the application running from inside Blend.

I know I should design things in a way that busy work is performed by backgroundworkers or threads, and perhaps avoid instantiation of viewmodels by views (using VM-first approach with templates, for example) but for now my question is:

> Is there a way to configure Expression Blend (2013) so that it doesn't "start" the objects it is displaying in the designer?

Answer (score 1):

In the code behind I strategically place the following code to ignore initializations and other items of graphical processing not needed in design mode.

This will *dummy down* the processing during design time, which I also o to fix `Object Reference` failures during design time:

WPF

`if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty)`

Silverlight

`if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)`